# When using grep on html files, how can I display only the text and not the tags?

Tags: grep, html

I have wgot a large website. Rather than setting up a local search engine I use grep to search the site. Grep's output shows the html (of course), but I only want to see the text (and not all the html tags).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Or something like [`xmllint`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176040/error-getting-the-string-between-two-patterns/176043#176043).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution I have found is piping grep's output to html2text:

```
sudo apt-get install html2text
grep "som* interesting" | html2text
```

This largely works, but it fails a) to keep the color highlighting of grep, b) to use unicode, and c) to replace certain characters. Here is a more complete alternative that does not have these disadvantages.

```
grep --color=always "test*" * | html2text -utf8 | sed 's/l&rsquo/\"/'
```

Of course you can edit the stream using sed to change other elements as well.

Comment: SHouldn't it be the other way around (`html2text | grep`) like KasiyA does?

Comment: I don't think so because in that case you lose the file names.

Comment: Also note that performing the change on the grep results is exponentially faster than performing the change on all the files to then grep the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Use `lynx` command and install it by following:

```
sudo apt-get install lynx-cur
```

[See the input and output here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_basic)

```
$ lynx --dump infile.html | grep 'PATTERN'
HTML Tables

   HTML tables start with a table tag.

   Table rows start with a tr tag.

   Table data start with a td tag.
     __________________________________________________________________

1 Column:

   100
     __________________________________________________________________

1 Row and 3 Columns:

   100 200 300
     __________________________________________________________________

3 Rows and 3 Columns:

   100 200 300
   400 500 600
   700 800 900
     __________________________________________________________________
```

---

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```bsh
awk '{gsub(/<[^>]*>/,"")} /PATTERN/{# what you want to do }' infile
```

Comment: Any way to use lynx, but not lose the file names? I am searching many documents, remember.

Comment: Grep displays the file names when giving the results (`somefile/somewhere:search result`). If you pipe to grep (rather than to start with grep) you lose the filenames...